# Get and Set in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, types, public, object-oriented-analysis

What can i add so that the age becomes public? I have to add something and not change it.

class Person{

```
   public name: string;
   private age: number; 



 constructor(name: string;  age:number) {

            this.name=name;
            this.age=age;   }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You need a Getter and a Setter :

```
class Person {
    public name: string;
    private age: number; 

    constructor(name: string;  age:number) {
        this.name=name;
        this.age=age;   
    }

    get age():number {
        return this.age;
    }
    set age(age:number) {
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

Comment: try this :set age(_age:number) {  this.age = _age;}

Comment: should i change age into _age  or something else?